# How to copy and save an audio file using c#?

Tags: c#

i want to copy and paste a audio file using c#?

```
    Int32 intAudioSize = 0;
    string strAudioType = null;
    Stream AudioStream = null;

    // Gets the Size of the Audio
    intAudioSize = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;

    // Gets the Audio Type
    strAudioType = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;

    // Reads the Audio
    AudioStream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28VS.71%29.aspx) method.

See [Copy, Delete, and Move Files and Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx)

***Edit***

To your edited question.

You can use [HttpPostedFile.SaveAs Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.saveas%28VS.80%29.aspx)

for saving a file that is selected using the `<input type="file" />` control

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are not going to do anything with it use [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(VS.71).aspx)

This is how it works for all kind of files : `File.Copy("source", "destination");`

and you should reference System.IO

Answer (score 0):

Use [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28VS.71%29.aspx):

```
File.Copy("file-from.mp3", "file-to.mp3");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `FileUpload.SaveAs("file.ext");`

See [MSDN's FileUpload page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx)